# How to get the first `href` string using jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

My code returns all the links on a webpage, but I would like to get the first link when I google search something for example "android". How do I do that?

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(sharedURL).get();
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                    stringBuilder.append(title).append("\n");
                    for (Element link : links) {
                        stringBuilder.append("\n").append(" ").append(link.text()).append(" ").append(link.attr("href")).append("\n");
                    }
```

Here ids my code

Answer (score 0):

### [`Elements#first`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first()) and [`Node#absUrl`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl(java.lang.String))

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Node node = links.first();
        System.out.println(node.absUrl("href"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi
```

Comment: @stankhoe - I've updated the answer. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: `does this code need to be put in a thread?` - It depends on your requirement.

Comment: okay so it worked but the first link is always "about us/help" its not "android"

Comment: @stankhoe - What's the URL you are trying to get `href` from?

Comment: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=youtube` is my URL. it should return `https://www.youtube.com` but it returns `https://www.duckduckgo.com/`

Comment: the interesting part is, if I use my method(extract all links), the first link is actually `https://www.youtube.com/`. I'm not sure why it is not working with your methoid

Comment: is there a regex for extracting the first link?